# SSH Broken pipe - but only over an LTE router

Tags: ssh

I have the latest version of MacOS and use SSH v2.7.3.
When at work I quite happily sign into our AWS servers via ssh and remain signed in even if terminal stays idle for hours.

At home I have an LTE router. I can sign in without issue, but if the terminal (and therefore the ssh connection) remain idle for longer than roughly 5 minutes the connection fails.

The error only appears once I try to type something. The error reads:

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Broken pipe
```

How can I determine WHY the connection closed? To me it's obvious that it's related to my LTE router, as both my laptop and my desktop have the same issue at home over the LTE router, yet the issue doesn't come up at work.

I simply don't have the know-how to troubleshoot the connection or play around with the settings on the LTE router.

Comment: Have you consulted either the manufacturer's tech support for the LTE router or the ISP providing the LTE service?  While there may be a general answer to your question, since the issue resides on the router and the manufacturer's info and firmware version weren't provided, it's unlikely a general answer would suffice.

Comment: I am still waiting on an answer from either :-(
The router is a Huawei B315

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got an answer from the ISP and they had a limiter on their network that affected this; support removed the limiter from my account and all was good again.